# how to replace letters by loop in java?

Tags: java

I am writing a cryptography program that converts the ciphertext to plaintext. By the letter's frequency, I manually crack all the cipher's letters to plaintext, and there is no patterns, so I need to write a loop that contains 26 times, to convert every single letter in the string to another letter.

My first try is using the replace statement in java,
which will be like this

```
str=str.replaceAll("A","E");
```

The question is, for instance, I input a string like this   `abc`
and my key will be like this    "replace a with c, replace b with p, replace c with q".
The output I want should be  `cpq`, but the output I got is `qpq`.
Which means I want it be like one time convert.

So I am trying to use the loop, using the if

The way I am doing it is:

```
for (i=1;i<string.length;i++)
    if (char[i]=="a")
        char [i] ="b";
```

The error tells me that I can't convert string to char.
And also, I want to ask if I put the other 25 if statements inside this statement or pararall them?

Comment: In Java, a `char` literal is enclosed within single, not double, quotes.

Comment: And `char` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question: I would not add 25 single `if` statements in your loop but instead use a `Map<Character, Character>` to store your replacements.

A complete solution could look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Character, Character> replacements = new HashMap<>();
    replacements.put('a', 'c');
    replacements.put('b', 'p');
    replacements.put('c', 'q');

    String input = "abcd";
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
        output.append(replacements.getOrDefault(c, c));
    }
    System.out.println(output.toString());
}
```

This will keep characters you don't have a replacement for. Output:

```
cpqd
```

Comment: Would you please explain the output.append(replacements.getOrDefault(c, c)); ? I run it, it works, but is that c is a special example, or you just did that for another reason?

Comment: `c` is the current character from the input string - `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` or `'d'`. And `Map#getOrDefault` is a new method introduced with Java 8 that returns the second argument when the map (`replacements`) does not have a value for the given key (`c`). In this case, the key happens to be the same as the desired default value. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V- for details.

Comment: another stupid question, how will you add a scanner and put this  String " input" as the scanner ? Do you import the library first ,and then you do Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine();

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but basically you only need to replace `String input = "abcd";` with `String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();`. See here: https://ideone.com/N0YTMd

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this as :

```
    String str = "abc";
    char [] ch = str.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        if('a'==str.charAt(i)){
            ch[i] = 'c';
        }
        if('b'==str.charAt(i)){
            ch[i] = 'p';
        }
        if('c'==str.charAt(i)){
            ch[i] = 'q';
        }
    }
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(ch));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful code, will try it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert a String to a char.  So you need to either use all Strings or all chars. Instead of using the double quotes for String you could use the single quotes for char like this:

```
char[i]=='b'
```

and

```
char[i] = 'b';
```

Also instead of using a long if/else statement you could either use a switch statement, or even better you could create and use a Map to store the conversions in key/value pairs.